# find the angle of a point on a circle

Tags: r, geometry, point, angle

I am given (x,y) points and I know the radius. I want to to find the angle of each point on circle. In the future I want to use this code as part of a test whether the angles are distributed uniformly on the interval [0,2Pi].

The code I've tried is

```
b <- matrix(c(d[,2],d[,5]),ncol=2)
S <- (b/sqrt((rowSums(b^2))))
#S <- matrix(S[!is.na(S)],ncol=2)
lim <- c(-1,1)
plot(S,xlim=lim,ylim=lim,xlab=expression(S1),ylab=expression(S2))
#S<-S[!is.na(S)]
U <- matrix(c(0),nrow=nrow(S),ncol=1)
for (i in 1:nrow(S)) {
    U[i,1] <- (atan(abs(S[i,1]/S[i,2])))
}
```

That code gave me some angles, but none lay in the interval [270,360].

[image: points on circle]

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the values of all the variables, such as `b`, and give the exact error message.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Your U_i are atan(abs(S[i,1]/S[i,2])). atan of a positive number is never in [270:360].

Comment: Use `atan2` instead of `atan`.

Answer (score 3):

Hi if you could give some simple sample of your data that would be very helpful.

However I can initially see some problems with the use of `atan()`.

1. `atan` takes a single argument and returns an angle in radians NOT degrees.
2. `atan` result is ambiguous because you dont know what quadrant the values are in. For instance there is not way of distinguishing whether a negative `x` value is because we are in the 2nd or 4th quadrant.

To solve this you can use `atan2()` which takes two arguments and thus removes the ambiguity [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). For intance:

using just `atan` you can see this problem (I am converting to degrees here)

```
atan(1/1) * 180/pi # first quadrant
# 45
atan(1/-1) * 180/pi # second quadrant
# -45
atan(-1/-1) * 180/pi # third quadrant
# 45
atan(-1/1) * 180/pi # fourth quadrant
# -45
```

As you can see you are only getting results on `[-90,90]` ( `[-pi/2, pi/2]` ).

But using `atan2()`

```
atan2(y = 1, x = 1) * 180/pi # first quadrant
# 45
atan2(y = 1, x = -1) * 180/pi # second quadrant
# 135
atan2(y = -1, x = -1) * 180/pi # third quadrant
# -135 same as 225 (360-135)
atan2(y = -1, x = 1) * 180/pi # fourth quadrant
# -45 same as 315 (360-45)
```

As you can see now you are able to remove the ambiguity surrounding which quadrant your values falls in using `atan2`.